# Html hover style for each row

Tags: html, css

This is my view table:

```
<tr>
       <th><p>ID</p></th>
       <th><p>NAME</p></th>
       <th><p>CLASS</p></th>
       <th><p>EDIT</p></th>
       <th><p>DELETE</p></th>
</tr>
```

This is my css file:

```
table.mytable tr{
 background-color: #ffff99;
}
```

For highlights rows using hover, it is not working for me. i don't know where i did wrongly kindly help on this issue?

Many thanks,
viswa

Comment: I don't see you use :hover rule for tr.

Answer (score 1):

User `:hover` selector to hover color:

```css
table.mytable tr:hover{
 background-color: #ffff99;
}
```

```html
<table class="mytable">
<tr>
       <th><p>ID</p></th>
       <th><p>NAME</p></th>
       <th><p>CLASS</p></th>
       <th><p>EDIT</p></th>
       <th><p>DELETE</p></th>
</tr>
<tr>
       <td>1</td>
       <td>ABC</td>
       <td>2</td>
       <td>edit</td>
       <td>delete</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

ADD `P:hover` selector to hover color:

```
p:hover{
 background-color: #ffff99;
}
```

Thanks

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/aq8bkkv4/1/)

**OR**

```
.mytable{
        width:100%; 
        border-collapse:collapse; 

    border:#4e95f4 1px solid;
    }
    .mytable td{ 
        padding:7px; 
    border:#4e95f4 1px solid;
    }

    .mytable tr{
        background: #b8d1f3;
    }

    .mytable tr:hover {
          background-color: #ffff99;
    }
```

[**DEMO UPDATED HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/aq8bkkv4/2/)

Comment: Hi Raj, Thanks for your answer. I followed your steps it is working fine , but i want to high lighter entire Row could you please help me ?

Comment: @user6420577 wait sir

Answer (score 0):

viswa.

To highlight on hover, you need to add the css for hover too. Since, you are enclosing your rows in `<p>` tags, you can use the following in you css file.

`p:hover{
  background-color: #ffff99;
}`

Make sure there is no space between : and the word 'hover'.

Comment: table.mytable td :hover{
  background-color: #ffff99;
}

Comment: I tried above method it is working for only one cell, but instaed of that i want high light entire row ?

Comment: I see. Please **update** the html and css code as following: html here: `<table class="mytable">
<tr>
       <th><p>ID</p></th>
       <th><p>NAME</p></th>
       <th><p>CLASS</p></th>
       <th><p>EDIT</p></th>
       <th><p>DELETE</p></th>
</tr>
</table>` and the css as below: `.mytable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
.mytable tr:hover {
  background:#ffff99;
}`   Once again, please make sure there's no space in "tr:hover"

Answer (score 0):

```
tr:hover {
      background-color: #ffff99;
    }
```

[Check here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lhh3f8eo/)